# How can I use an expression with the context of the call location as a parameter in a partial?

Tags: handlebars.js, frontend, web-frontend

For example in a handlebars template:

```
{{#each data }}
   {{> partial parameter=somethingFromThisContext }}
{{/each}}
```

and then in my partial:

```
{{ somethingFromThisContext }}
{{ data }}
```

Neither of them work. If I use a string as a parameter instead of data, the string will display, but all the other expressions in the partial will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood you correctly, but you seem to have misunderstood handlebars' partial behaviour.

Inside a partial your scope will not be accessible, so you won't have access to any parameters you have in the template where you call your partial.

To pass parameters you have to assign them in the partial call like you did:
`{{> partial parameter=somethingFromThisContext }}`. However you've renamed your `somethingFromThisContext` to `parameter` now. So it's accessible like so: `{{parameter}}`.

It's like doing something like this in any programming language:

`paramter = somethingFromThisContext;`

[There is a pretty nice Documentation page here, which may guide you further.](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html)